# Any way to customize the color of the text input cursor?

Tags: customization, theme

[image]

That one, can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. I checked the general 'User Interface' theme section, the 'Text Editor' cursor colour and I even went so far as to check any items which are blue in the other theme settings just in case they might affect it. Unfortunately none of them did. I also checked other areas of the user preferences as there are a few theme-like settings in other sections but to no avail. While the majority of Blender's interface is customisable, there are a few things which aren't and I think this is one of them.

Comment: Could this be added to blender some time, what do you think?

Comment: @Monkok It's doubtful, but you never know, it might get included when the UI and themes are looked at in 2.8. Best thing to do is raise it on the [BF-Inerface mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-interface)